# Is there any possibility of a goroutine interrupt without panic?

Tags: go

i'm setting up a service, provide http server and run goroutine to deal with some job, look code

once in a cycle, a sub job seems like interrupt， there is no logs after one func call

it didn't catch any panic err, and the defer seems not trigger because the mutex lock is not unlock

the log is not interrupted or lost
log of other job is complete
there is no restart or exit or oom kill on those time

this is for a CentOS 7.5, my service running in docker

go1.11
docker 18.09

this is an occasional bug, i add more log and open pprof, and try to reproduce this bug

main.go

```golang
func main() {
    ....
    // this is a cycle job, with custom time intervals
    router.Cycle(r)
    ....
    endless.ListenAndServe(":"+conf.Conf.Port, r)
}
```

router/cycle.go

```golang
// this is a loop job, when job end, sleep custom time intervals and run again
// implemented by encapsulating a goroutine, and create a context 
func Cycle(g *gin.Engine) {
    cyclec := cli.InitCycle(g)
    cyclec.AddFunc(time.Second, schedule.RunSomeDeal)
    cyclec.Start()
}

///RunSomeDeal
func RunSomeDeal(c *gin.Context) error {
    ...
    // deal some sub job
    for i := 0; i < missionLen; i++ {
                // this is once job, like cycle but only run once
                // a new context is generated by passing the exist context and a goroutine executes the callback function
        helpers.Job.Run(c, func(newCtx *gin.Context) error {
                        return DealMission(newCtx, someparams...)
        })
    }
    return nil
}

// Job.Run
func (c *Job) Run(ctx *gin.Context, f func(ctx *gin.Context) error) {
    e := &Entry{
        Job: FuncJob(f),
    }

    if c.getJobContext != nil {
        e.span = c.getJobContext(ctx)
    }
    go c.runWithRecovery(e)
}

func (c *Job) runWithRecovery(e *Entry) {
    ctx := gin.CreateNewContext(c.gin)
    ...
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            const size = 64 << 10
            buf := make([]byte, size)
            buf = buf[:runtime.Stack(buf, false)]

            requestId, _ := ctx.Get("requestId")
            handleName := ctx.CustomContext.HandlerName()
            info, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{
                ...some kv for log
            })
            log.Printf(...)
        }
        gin.RecycleContext(c.gin, ctx)
    }()

    if c.beforeRun != nil {
        ok := c.beforeRun(ctx, e.span)
        if !ok {
            return
        }
    }

    error := e.Job.Run(ctx)
    ...
    if c.afterRun != nil {
        c.afterRun(ctx)
    }
}


// DealMission

func DealMission(c *gin.Context, params...) {
    // lock something use sync.mutex
    doSomeLock()

    defer func() {
        // ...not trigger
        unlockErr := unlockxxxxx(...)
        if unlockErr != nil {
            panic("some error info")
        }
    } ()

    base.DebugLog(...)
    err := SomeOtherFunc(c, params...)
    base.DebugLog(...)
}

// some other func
func SomeOtherFunc(ctx *gin.Context, params...) error {
    err := CallOther()
    base.DebugLog(...)

    err := CallOther()
    base.DebugLog(...)

    //  there is no logs after this call func, and Job.runWithRecovery not catch any panic error
    err := CallOther()
    // print log...  
    base.DebugLog(...)
}
```

in this sub job, the log stop at a certain line， and no panic，no error， and the defer seems not trigger because the mutex lock is not unlock

log for other job is well, and log of next cycle job is well too

Comment: It can be interrupted as in put on hold while another goroutine runs on that thread, but it won't exit. A goroutine is the function called with `go x()`; just like any other function call, it does not stop until it panics or returns.

Comment: You probably have a lock contention issue or something along those lines - when you think the routine is hung, send your app a `SIGQUIT` to get a stack trace of all running goroutines, that should help find where the issue is.

Comment: If you have tests, try running it with the race detector.
go test -race ./...

Comment: you do not need testing suite to check for race detection `go build -race` or `go run -race` also works.